# Constructing new categories by adding structure

Tags: ct.category-theory, monoidal-categories, universal-property

On the one hand, let $\mathcal{C}$ be the monoidal category of finite-dimensional complex vector spaces and linear transformations, and on the other, let $\mathcal{D}$ be the monoidal category of finite-dimensional Hilbert spaces and unitary transformations. Intuitively, $\mathcal{D}$ is obtained from $\mathcal{C}$ by adding structure to the objects and requiring morphisms to be isomorphisms that intertwine that additional structure, and a standard way to make this intuition rigorous is to observe that there is a faithful monoidal functor $\mathcal{D} \to \mathcal{C}$, the obvious forgetful functor.

Here’s my question: instead of defining the monoidal category structure on $\mathcal{D}$ from scratch (albeit in the obvious way) and then showing that the would-be forgetful functor is a well-defined faithful monoidal functor, is there a setting in which one could safely *induce* the monoidal category $\mathcal{D}$ from its class of would-be objects, its class of would-be morphisms, the monoidal category $\mathcal{C}$, and the would-be forgetful functor $\mathcal{D} \to \mathcal{C}$ as defined on would-be objects and would-be morphisms?

I’m writing up some work where I have to carry out constructions very similar to the initial example again and again and again, but I’m not confident enough in my naïve category theory to define something as the unique monoidal category making the obvious forgetful functor into a faithful monoidal functor—but perhaps this is actually OK? Off the top of my head, I realise there may be an issue with specifying how the monoidal product interacts with that additional structure, but I don't know how to formalise this concern.

Comment: Isn't your example (Hilbert spaces and finite-dimensional vector spaces) a counter-example already? At least I don't see how the Hilbert tensor product could be "induced" abstractly from the ordinary tensor product.

Comment: Hence my final comment. You obviously can’t abstractly induce the tensor product inner product. But once you’ve specified what that is, you can then check that a tensor product of unitaries is still a unitary and that all the relevant structure morphisms from $\mathcal{C}$ remain unitaries. Now you have would-be objects, would-be morphisms, a would-be tensor product, and would-be coherence morphisms: is one stuck proving that $\mathcal{D}$ is a monoidal category from scratch (while exploiting ad hoc its construction from $\mathcal{C}$), or is there something more systematic?